# Socket Programming using command line arguments for port number and IP address

Tags: c, sockets, command-line-arguments

The below code takes command line arguments as input and makes a socket ready for listening for the incoming packets from client side, however it is not running at some stage getting halted as the port number entered through command line is not getting feed as the same,

Pls guide what could be the possible error

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <arpa/inet.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include "p8log.h"
    #include <errno.h>


    #define FIRST_SIZE 1
    #define SECOND_SIZE 6
    #define THIRD_SIZE 16


    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
           /*some code*/
 if (fd != NULL)
        {


                struct sockaddr_in serverAddr, clientAddr;
                struct sockaddr_storage serverStorage;
                socklen_t addr_size, client_addr_size;


                /*Create UDP socket*/
                udpSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
                if (udpSocket==-1)
                        LERR("Error in creating the socket with the error number <%s>",strerror(errno) );

                /*Configure settings in address struct*/
                serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
                serverAddr.sin_port = htons((int)*PORT);
                serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IPADDR);
                memset(serverAddr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof serverAddr.sin_zero);

                /*Bind socket with address struct*/

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
Execution of the program:
./a.out 11111 127.0.0.1


 Output:
Arg Count=3
Arguments are=./UDPserver,11111,127.0.0.1
port num=11111
IP ADDR=127.0.0.1
```

### -------------------------------------------------------------------

Client Side Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>


#define PORT 11111
#define IPADDR "127.0.0.1"


int main(){
  /*some code*/
}
```

Comment: You cannot convert `PORT` to an integer by casting.  It is a char pointer.  You need to use `atoi()` or `atol()` to get an integer then pass it to `htons()`.

Comment: @MartinJames, sir am learning things, pls in this life of being human, never ever demotivate anyone....instead brother u can help me out by guiding me what shall i refer to make my string handling operations more strong?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your server, `PORT` is a `char*`.

When you pass "11111", `*PORT` (a.k.a. `PORT[0]`) is `'1'`, and `(int)*PORT` is most likely 49.

You need to convert to an integer, using for instance `atoi`.